Возможно ли использовать yandex-geocoding-api без доступа в интернет
Сайт должен обеспечивать поиск объекта как имея доступ к интернету так и без него. Возможно ли и каким образом реализовать работу без доступа к интернет. Сейчас использую OSM, но хотелось бы как карту так и yandex-geocoding-api использовать без доступа к www
